# I want to make a gallery with fixed row width wordpress (pseudo-code)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, pseudocode

This is an example of what Id like to do.
http://www.davidmielcarek.com/

I'd like the rows to be fixed length but I might have 2 or 3 images per row.

I attempted this earlier and it didn't really work.

Here is the pseudo code

```
    start loop
       get image width
       calculate rowWidth
       if (rowWidth > maxRowWidth){
          start nested loop
             grab thumbnails for this row only
             resize the thumbnails using the row's aspect ratio so each row is the same width
             call the thumbnails
          end nested loop
          reset some variables for the next row
          check if this is the last post
       }
    end loop
```

I don't see the issue but when I put it into actual code I couldn't get it working perhaps someone else can code it better or point out my flaw?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how that is done - I would guess they are using JS and/or CSS to set the image as a background on an element, rather than re-sizing the actual image. All you have to do then is control the size of your `div`.

Comment: that is probably an easier solution than I was thinking.  I'll look into it.  I think this guy just hard coded his thumbnails to fit.  But I'm not sure.  It would still have to be dynamic because you aren't always going to want rows of size x and y.  You want them to be decided by the image dimensions.

Comment: The codex says . As of Version 2.5, this parameter does not affect the size of media icons, which are always shown at their original size. and this might be causing me problems but its not very specific what constitutes a media icon

Comment: I'd imagine his images are resized by a theme plugin when uploaded / used as a post image. They are all set to the same height - all you need to know is the width after that. Make sure you don't set the width of the div to wider than the image, and you're set. (I checked his source, he is using CSS to put the images as backgrounds that are centered).

Comment: I appreciate you taking a closer look at it with me.